# Do all chromosomes in one human body contains same genome?

Tags: dna, chromosome, gene, genomes

As I understand it, each nucleus of a cell contains multiple chromosomes. Each chromosome has multiple DNAs. Each DNA contains some specific gene sequences. That sequence is called Genome.

My question, do all chromosomes in cells in a human body contain same types of genomes (i.e. gene sequences)?

Comment: About your first paragraph, a correct phrasing would be "Each nucleus contains multiple chromosomes, each chromosome contains 2 strands of DNA (although it depends on the timing in the life-cycle). The genetic information is in the sequence of amino acids that make up the DNA. DNA. The genome is the entire genetic sequence of an individual."

Comment: @Remi.b, where does the gene stand in your description?

Comment: A gene is a vaguely defined functional unit of the genome :). It corresponds to a given locus (position on the genome) and often contain a coding region (a coding region is a sequence which is translated and transcribed into protein). Have a look at wikipedia for more definitions. As everyone can see the comments, I edited your post to remove your copy-paste of my comment.

Comment: @Remi.b, how is my question a duplicate here? I couldn't figure it out !!!!????

Comment: You are correct, the post I linked is not a duplicate. Sorry about that, I'm removing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, all cells contains the same genome. This is because, for a given individual, all of its cells comes from the [zygote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygote), a singular cell formed after fecondation of the maternal ovum and paternal spermatozoa, through repeated cell division ([mitosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitosis)). This is a process which replicates quite exactly the genome that will be passed to the newly formed cells.

There are some exceptions however, such as :

- [Red blood cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_blood_cell), and [platelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platelet) : these cells lack a nucleus, and don't contain DNA at all.
- Cells bearing mutation(s) : even though the replication machinery try to make an exact copy of the DNA, error(s) may happens.
- [Gametes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamete) : ovum and spermatozoa are produced through [meiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis), a specific replication mechanism that keeps only half the genome, and may produce new sequences through [recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_recombination#Meiotic_recombination).
- Lymphocytes undergo [V(D)J recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V(D)J_recombination) and [somatic hypermutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatic_hypermutation) which alters their DNA, a process that is necessary to the working of our immune system.